# Is this search code with any date format as the following right? or not?

Tags: c#, sql, date, search

Is this search code with any date format as the following right? to catch date format "dd-MM-yyyy".
My table is:

```
id |   dat    | user | remain
-----------------
1 | 01-03-2013 | x | 1000
----------------
2 | 01-03-2013 | x | 1200
----------------
3 | 02-03-2013 | y | 1100
----------------
4 | 02-03-2013 | y | 1300
----------------
5 | 03-03-2013 | z | 1200
----------------
6 | 03-03-2013 | z | 1400
-------------------------

private void textBox10_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((textBox10.Text == "yyyy/MM/dd") || (textBox10.Text == "dd/MM/yyyy") || (textBox10.Text == "yyyy-MM-dd"))
        {
            textBox10.Text = "dd-MM-yyyy";
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Class1.x))
            {
                cn.Open();
                string cm = "select id from item_treasury where dat='" + textBox10.Text + "' order by id";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cm, cn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read() == true)
                        {
                            if (dr.HasRows == false)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                                this.Close();
                            }
                            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to correct this code.
Kindly help me!

Comment: No this is not right. This is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), the worst kind... Use prepared statements!

Comment: Also this doesn't pass the date itself it passes the format. What are you trying to do here pass in a date format? Also textBox10 is not a helpful name, neither is comboBox1 you should probably change these.

Comment: Why any typing not as text search as "dd-MM-yyyy" the program doesn't response?

Comment: You should use parameters and pass the date to SQL server as a *date* and not as some arbitrarily formatted string. And, hopefully, on the server side, the data is stored in a column with type `datetime` (or one of the more modern variants). Storing or treating dates as strings is one of the largest sources of (date-related) bugs.

Comment: I want if I entered 02/03/2013 into textBox10.Text the result is (3) and (4) into comboBox1.Items, if my text entered not as state previous the program gives me a message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a date like 31/12/2012 in your text box, so you do want have it as a date and the do you sql query with that date. At this moment you just looking for the formatting string in the TextBox.

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox10.Text, (... date formats in string array), null, null, out date)
{
    ....
         string cm = "select id from item_treasury where dat='" + date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "' order by id";
    ....
}
```

Better whould be to save the dates as dates in your database and use parameterized queries to retrieve your data.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I want if I entered 02/03/2013 into textBox10.Text the result is (3) and (4) into comboBox1.Items, if my text entered not as state previous the program gives me a message.

Comment: new string[] {"dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy" }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all,
My final right code:

```
DateTime date;
        string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy", "d-MM-yyyy", "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy/M/dd", "yyyy-M-dd", "dd/M/yyyy", "dd-M-yyyy" }; //////////if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox10.Text, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox10.Text, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Class1.x))
            {
                cn.Open();
                string cm = "select id from item_treasury where dat='" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' order by id";
                ///////////****
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cm, cn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read() == true)
                        {
                            if (dr.HasRows == false)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                                this.Close();
                            }
                            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```